# Question about working in modulo?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question is in essence asking for understanding of a step in Fermats theorem done Group style.

For any field the nonzero elements form a group under field multiplication. So let us take the Field $Z_p$. The group $Z_p$ - {0} form a group under field multiplication.

This is my question. For any group $G$, let $a$ be an element of $G$, then

$1)$$H$ = {$a^n$| $n$ is an element of $Z$}

If we are working in $Z_p$ does that mean we can restrict the $n$ in equation 1 to just the elements from $0$ to $p-1$?

Thanks yall

Comment: since I recieved +1 and a √ , you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ${\Bbb Z}_p-\{0\}$ has order $p-1$ then, by a Fermat's theorem $x^{p-1}=1$ for each $x$ there. This isn't mean that the order of $x$ is $p-1$, but asures you that this number is $\le p-1$.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was looking for. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

It is a theorem that a finite subgroup of the nonzero elements of a field is cyclic, and as a corollary, the nonzero elements of a finite field form s cyclic group.

If the field is size n, the subgroup is size $n-1$, and yes, the first n powers of any element suffice to generate the cyclic subgroup generated by an element. In fact, even that is overkill, often.

Comment: So an element to the p-1 power in the set I just gave you will give me the identity element? Why is that the case?

Comment: @user121615, this is the content of the **Little Fermat's Thm**: See it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: @user121515 the order of an element of a group divides the size of the group, that's why.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's Fermat's little theorem, but this result is being used to prove Fermat's little theorem. I get the order divides the set and should equal 1. I just don't understand why an element that isn't 0 raised to the p-1 power is a subgroup and the order of the element

Comment: @user121615, look: in ${\Bbb Z}_5$ we have $4^2=1$, so the order for $4$ is two.

Comment: What's happening in the example i cited is an element from $Z_p$ being raised to the $p-1$ power seems to get you the identity element according to this. Why is that the case? It's more equivalent to taking $3^4$ power. What I am asking is that any element from the group I typed in question, raised to the $p-1$ power is the identity.

Comment: @user121615 do you understand that the order of an element in a finite group divides the size of the group?